# Searching for matches of (numeric) string in a huge list in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, list, search

I have a *sorted* list of numbers (10 million) that are in character format, and each entry is constant length of 15 characters. Think like:

```
100000000000000
100000000000001
...
100000010000000
```

Now I want to create a  regular breakdown in this list, to see how entries are being accumulated in different ranges. The output could be like this:

```
100000000xxxxxx, 523121 entries
100000001xxxxxx, 32231 entries
```

Currently I have tried reading the whole list to a set, and search through it. I have tried both, `string` and `int` format. The integer version is **3 times** faster than the string version currently. The codes look like:

```
collection_str = set(line.strip() for line in open(inputfile)
collection_int = set(int(line.strip()) for line in open(sys.argv[1]))

def find_str(look_for, ourset):
    count = 0
    for entry in ourset:
            if entry.startswith(look_for):
                    count += 1
    return count

def find_int(look_for, ourset):
    search_min = int(str(look_for) + "000000")
    search_max = int(str(look_for+1) + "000000")

    count = 0
    for entry in ourset:
            if entry >= search_min and entry < search_max:
                    count += 1
    return count
```

The results look like this:

```
"int version"
100000100 27401 (0.515992sec)
100000101 0 (0.511334sec)
100000102 0 (0.510956sec)
100000103 0 (0.510467sec)
100000104 0 (0.512834sec)
100000105 0 (0.511501sec)

"string version"
100000100 27401 (1.794804sec)
100000101 0 (1.794449sec)
100000102 0 (1.802035sec)
100000103 0 (1.797590sec)
100000104 0 (1.793691sec)
100000105 0 (1.796785sec)
```

I wonder if I could somehow make it even faster ? Even with 0,5s / range, this still takes time if I want run this often to create some periodic statistics...
From searches around I see that some people use `bisect` for something similar, but I can't seem to get my head around how it should work.

Comment: Can you upload the sample file? I would like to try this.

Comment: `bisect` is for binary searching.

Comment: for ranges: sort first, then binary searching.

for elements: use a dict and use `in` operator.

Comment: I suppose could generate something..  but the data is employers property ;)
Hang on

Comment: @SaltyEgg, Ah - sorry, indeed I have pre-sorted the list. Added that to the question

Comment: Why do you store your data in a set(to remove dumplicates)?

Comment: @glasslion A habit really - I have a recollection than going through a set is faster than going through a list..

Comment: If the file is too large to load into memory, you should build a index for it first. For example, partition the numbers into cells (100 or 1000 numbers per cell), then you can first calculate which cell the query lies in, and then do searching in a small cell.

Comment: How many numbers are there in your test? If takes 0,5s / range when   the number 27401, it world takes much longer when the number is 10 million

Comment: Use `in` operator to find existence of a key in a `dict` is much more faster than go through a `set`.

Comment: If you need the speed, use bisect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it into a numpy array. Then you can use vectorisation which is nice and fast :)

```
from random import randint
import numpy
ip = numpy.array(['1{0:014d}'.format(randint(0, 10000000)) for x in xrange(10000000)], dtype=numpy.int64)

numpy.sum(ip <= 100000000010000)
# 9960
%timeit numpy.sum(ip <= 100000000010000)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 35 ms per loop
```

Putting this in terms of your search functions:

```
import numpy

def find_numpy(look_for, ourset):
    search_min = int('{0:0<15s}'.format(str(look_for)))
    search_max = int('{0:0<15s}'.format(str(look_for+1)))
    return numpy.sum((ourset >= search_min) & (ourset < search_max))

with open('path/to/your/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    ip = numpy.array([line.strip() for line in f], dtype=numpy.int64)

find_numpy(1000000001, ip)
# 99686
%timeit find_numpy(1000000001, ip)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 86.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit ? You're trying to run `sum` (according to manual "sum of array elemenst over a given axis" on elements that are smaller than `100000000010000`? Wouldn't `100000000010001` give wrong result then ? I seem to always get 0 as a result...

Comment: Just edited for more clarity and put in terms of your other search functions.

Comment: Essentially, we're reading your list in to a numpy array of `dtype=numpy.int64` which will convert all of your strings to integers. Now we can essentially follow the logic of your integer search, but using numpy's vectorisation rather than looping.

Comment: To read your file in: `numpy.array([line.strip() for line in open(file)], dtype=numpy.int64)`

Comment: ```ip <= 100000000010000``` produces an array of True/False values and sum() treats True as one and False as zero.

Comment: @JoshaInglis this works great! it's about 14 times faster than the integer one I had worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

If the list is sorted, bisect will find the index that meets your criteria using a [bisection search](http://www.pembinatrails.ca/fortrichmondcollegiate/compsci/bluej/sorts/page6.htm).  It looks like bisect is much faster than using a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import bisect
from random import randint
from timeit import Timer

ip = ['1{0:014d}'.format(randint(0, 10000000)) for x in xrange(10000000)]
ip = sorted(ip)
print bisect.bisect(ip, '100000000010000')
# 9869
t = Timer("bisect.bisect(ip, '100000000010000')", 'from __main__ import bisect, ip')
print t.timeit(100)
# 0.000268309933485 seconds

ip_int = map(int, ip)
print bisect.bisect(ip_int, 100000000010000)
# 9869
t = Timer("bisect.bisect(ip_int, 100000000010000)", 'from __main__ import bisect, ip_int')
print t.timeit(100)
# 0.000137443078672 seconds

ip_numpy = np.array(ip_int)
print np.sum(ip_numpy <= 100000000010000)
# 9869
t = Timer("np.sum(ip_numpy <= 100000000010000)", 'from __main__ import np, ip_numpy')
print t.timeit(100)
# 8.23690123071 seconds
```

[Binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)